# Cannot find symbol error on java?

Tags: java, jtable

I am getting this error:

```
   symbol  : constructor JTable(float[][],java.lang.String[])
    location: class javax.swing.JTable
    table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames );
```

below is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class benchtesting extends JFrame
{

    private     JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private     JPanel      panel1;
    private     JPanel      panel2;
    private     JPanel      panel3;
private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;


    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        benchtesting mainFrame  = new benchtesting();
        mainFrame.setVisible( true );
    }

public benchtesting()
    {

        setSize(280,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(1300,280);
        setTitle("Photoreceptor Analysis");

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );

        // Create the tab pages
        createPage1();
    //  createPage2();
    //  createPage3();

        // Create a tabbed pane
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab( "Table", panel1 );
        tabbedPane.addTab( "Intensity Map", panel2 );
        tabbedPane.addTab( "Notes", panel3 );
        topPanel.add( tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
}


    public void createPage1()
    {

panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    float dataValues_all[]= new float[400]; 

BufferedReader inputFile2=null;
BufferedReader inputFile=null;

            try {
    FileReader freader =new FileReader("results.txt");
        inputFile2 = new BufferedReader(freader); 


    String read = "";
    String number ="";

    for (int linenum=0; linenum<400; linenum++) {

    read = inputFile2.readLine();


  if(read != null && read.startsWith("D"))
     {

                number = read.substring(9,15);  
                float real_numbers = Float.parseFloat(number);  

            real_numbers= real_numbers*2817217;
            System.out.println(Math.round(real_numbers)+" cells/mm^2"); 
        dataValues_all[linenum] = real_numbers; 
     } 
         }

         // System.out.println("hmm "+dataValues_all[398]); 

        String columnNames[] = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    float dataValues[][]= new float [1][10]; //1 row, 10 coloumns 


dataValues[0][0] = dataValues_all[2];
dataValues[0][1] = dataValues_all[6];
dataValues[0][2] = dataValues_all[10];
dataValues[0][3] = dataValues_all[14];
dataValues[0][4] = dataValues_all[18];
dataValues[0][5] = dataValues_all[22];
dataValues[0][6] = dataValues_all[26];
dataValues[0][7] = dataValues_all[30];
dataValues[0][8] = dataValues_all[34];
dataValues[0][9] = dataValues_all[38];


table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames );

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
panel1.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );



      } catch( Exception y ) {  y.printStackTrace();    } 

}}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error on compile? Are you getting it during runtime? What does your classpath look like? Details, we need them.

Comment: FYI: Compilation fails at line 108 at `table = new JTable(dataValues, columnNames );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `JTable` expects the arguments `(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)`. So when calling that constructor you need to call it with values of that types.

Passing `String[]` as `Object[]` is no problem (because a `String` is an `Object`, but passing `float[][]` as `Object[][]` is not valid (because a `float` **is not** an `Object`).

With Java5 the "boxing" of primitive type (like `float`) into wrapper objects (like `Float`) became possible. This means, that `Float a = 0.1f;` is valid. However boxing is not available for arrays.

Probably the best solution for your problem is to change your variable `dataValues` to type `Float[][]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a multidimensional array of primitive types. You need to use a multidimensional array of objects.

This is invalid:

```
float[][] arr;
```

This is valid:

```
Float[][] arr;
```

Comment: This is not true at all. You can do float[][] array or int[][] just fine. You are confusing it with List or Collection.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar: of course you can do **float[][]** arrays. You just can't use it to construct a **JTable**. Read the answer on question's context and some perspective!

Answer (score 0):

There is no matching constructor for [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) which expects the first parameter to extend `Object[][]`. `float` is a primitive type and does not extend `Object`. [Float](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) is an object which does. Use it instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone on the whole primitive/object information.
I changed float to Float and it works.

Answer (score 0):

float is a primitive type, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29). You probably need to make a `Float[][]` (the object)

Answer (score 0):

JTable class really does  not have constructor that accepts 2 dimensional float array and regular string array. It has constructor

`JTable(Object[], String[])`

So, just change

`float dataValues[][]= new float [1][10];`

to

`Object dataValues[][]= new Object [1][10];`

and enjoy. Say "thanks" to autoboxing...

Answer (score 0):

```
JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Constructs a JTable to display the values in the two dimensional array, rowData, with column names, columnNames.

As stated already, constructor takes object, you can't pass primitive multidimensional array.